# How to read out an .rgba16Float MTLTexture via getBytes()

Tags: swift, metal

I have problems reading out an MTLTexture which has a pixel format of .rgba16Float, the main reason is that Swift does not seem to have a corresponding SIMD4 format.

For .rgba32Float I can simply use the SIMD4< Float > format, like so

```
if let texture = texture {
    let region = MTLRegionMake2D(x, y, 1, 1)

    let texArray = Array<SIMD4<Float>>(repeating: SIMD4<Float>(repeating: 0), count: 1)
    texture.getBytes(UnsafeMutableRawPointer(mutating: texArray), bytesPerRow: (MemoryLayout<SIMD4<Float>>.size * texture.width), from: region, mipmapLevel: 0)
    let value = texArray[0]
}
```

This works fine as the Swift Float data type is 32bit, how can I do the same for a 16 bit .rgba16Float texture ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use vImage to convert the buffer from 16-bit to 32-bit float first. Check out [`vImageConvert_Planar16FtoPlanarF`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/1533030-vimageconvert_planar16ftoplanarf). **But** not that the documentation on the site is wrong (it's from another function...). I found [this utility](https://gist.github.com/codelynx/eeaeeda00828568aaf577c0341964c38) that demonstrate the process.

It would be more efficient, however, if you could use Metal to convert the texture into 32-bit float (or directly render into a 32-bit texture in the first place).

Comment: Thanks for the answer Frank. I actually thought I just missed the appropriate Swift data type. I cannot render into 32 bit directly as I need mipmaps which are not supported on 32 bit floats on iOS. I will looking into vImageConvert or convert the texture.

Comment: There's actually an open pull request for a Float16 type for Swift: https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/21738. But it's probably taking some time before it gets into release.

Comment: Do you need to read all mipmap levels at once? Otherwise, you could run an additional pass to just convert the layer you are interested in to 32-bit using Metal.

Comment: Yes, converting the layer is the best possible way for me right now, thanks for the help! Cool to hear re Float16 type, guess complete SIMD support for that is not trivial, but great that they want todo it.

Comment: It is probably more efficient to leave it in f16 on the device and use the getBytes method in conjunction with vImageConvert_Planar16FtoPlanarF on a scanline by scanline basis to effect the conversion. This allows the GPU to avoid using excess memory and the conversion will operate efficiently out of the L1 cache.